# Firebase Dynamic Links Considered as spam only on Facebook and Facebook is not showing the meta data Preview

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, deep-linking, dynamic-linking

I am using the Firebase SDK on Android to generate dynamic links.

Everything is working fine, and the generated dynamic links are working like a charm on Twitter, Google Plus, and many other platforms.

On the other hand, on Facebook, it's not working.

Facebook is not able to show the preview metadata (title, description, and image) and after a couple of sharing tries.

My DLs become blacklisted on Facebook and automatically deleted from Facebook.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: have the same problem, created a bug for Google: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116693455

Comment: +1 Having same issues on my end. Using our link https://nexusgamingtv.page.link/DmqJkwquRF11Nbih8.
Any updates on this mate? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue..

If you don't want to wait until Facebook unban "*.page.link" domain, maybe creating a landing page within your own domain name is a good temporary idea...

ex: app.yourdomain.com/abc is a landing page with button linked to xxx.page.link/abc

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with the same problem too. So, instead of defining metadata in my html page, I put the metadata right in the URL.

You just have to append `&st=PageTitle&sd=PageDescription&si=urlForImage` to the dynamic link generated. See the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/link-previews) for more info.

The resulting link is long so just use `buildShortDynamicLink()` provided by Firebase SDK to shorten the URL. Check out the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/create).